# How to download content and update UI in Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having an issue in downloading multiple image from server with ui updation. Problem is this that I have folders of wallpaper on server and I want to download images, I run a background worker to download images and to update my UI and my UI updation will be done once my all images gets downloaded(BackgroundWorker_Completed). But I want my UI to be updated every time when one folder of images gets downloaded as shown in below given image.

[image]

In above given example every folder contains multiple images such as Movies, Games, India etc and they have images of their belonging category e.g. in movies their are folders say Man Of Steel, Priest etc. Now when I am downloading my images they should be visible on UI every they gets downloads not in once at last. Code for downloading wallpaper given below:

---

**Background Worker Code For Downloading Images**

```
  void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    DataSet dsFile = Global.ReadConfig;

                    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(dsFile.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString());
                    string s = xDoc.Root.Name.ToString();
                    var countNode = xDoc.Root.Elements().Count();
                    for (int i = 0; i < countNode; i++)
                    {
                        XNode childNode = xDoc.Root.Nodes().ElementAt(i);
                        XElement ele = (XElement)childNode;
                        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Wallpaper\\" + ele.Name;

                        var movieList = from a in xDoc.Root.Descendants(ele.Name).Elements()
                                        select a;
                        foreach (var a in movieList)
                        {
                            string newpath = path + "\\" + a.Value;
                            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(newpath);
                            if (!di.Exists)
                            {
                                DirectoryInfo dinew = Directory.CreateDirectory(newpath);
                                filedownload(dsFile.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString() + "/Wallpaper/" + ele.Name + "/" + dinew.Name + "/", newpath + "\\");   
                            }
                        }
                        //new DesktopThemes.App_Page.MainWindow().getWallLink(ele.Name.LocalName);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            }
```

---

**Background Worker Completed to display image on UI**

```
void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string N = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\Wallpaper\" ;

            Random random = new Random();

            List<String> backimage = new List<String>();

            DirectoryInfo diback = new DirectoryInfo(N);
            // diback.GetFiles();

            Directory.GetFiles(N, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (var imagename in diback.GetFiles("*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                backimage.Add(imagename.Directory + "\\" + imagename.Name);
            }
            try
            {
                Image image = new Image();
                Uri add = new Uri(backimage[random.Next(0, backimage.Count - 1)]);
                image.Source = new BitmapImage(add);

                pnlBackground.Source = image.Source;
                this.Photos.Path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"Wallpaper\";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

---

**Code For downloading images Which is being called from background worker**

```
    public static void filedownload(String url, string downloadlocation)
        {
            FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@username, @password);
            ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            List<string> directories = new List<string>();
            string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
            {
                directories.Add(line);
                line = streamReader.ReadLine();
            }
            streamReader.Close();
            using (WebClient ftpClient = new WebClient())
            {
                ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(@username, @password);
                for (int i = 0; i <= directories.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (directories[i].Contains("."))
                    {
                        string path = url + directories[i].ToString();
                        string trnsfrpth = downloadlocation + directories[i].ToString();                            if (!new System.IO.FileInfo(trnsfrpth).Exists)
                        {
                            ftpClient.DownloadFile(path, trnsfrpth);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide the additional XAML-Code. It seems your binding is not updated but its hard to tell without the XAML

Comment: @lokusking `pnlBackground.Source = image.Source;` implies that there are no bindings.

Comment: <WrapPanel x:Name="panel" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <ListBox 
     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
     x:Name="PhotosListBox" 
     Style="{StaticResource PhotoListBoxStyle}" 
     Margin="5" 
     SelectionMode="Extended" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
     SelectedIndex="0" 
      d:IsHidden="True"
                        MouseDoubleClick="PhotosListBox_MouseDoubleClick">
                            </ListBox>
                        </WrapPanel>

Comment: The major problem is that you are creating all BitmapImages at once in the RunWorkerCompleted handler. An alternative would be to create each BitmapImage right after download (in DoWork). You have to make sure to set the `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` flag during creation and call the `Freeze()` method to make it cross-thread accessible. Assigning the bitmap to an Image control would have to be done in the UI thread by e.g. `Dispatcher.Invoke()`. Besides that having an intermediate Image control just for `pnlBackground.Source = image.Source` is entirely redundant.

Comment: I'd suggest to have an `ObservableCollection<ImageSource>` (which is updated via a Dispatcher call), and bind the ListBox to that collection. Then declare an Image control in the ItemTemplate of the ListBox and bind its Source property to the collection element, like `<Image Source="{Binding}" />`.

Comment: @Clemens It seems that your solution would be working on my code. Please can you give the code to implement this cause I have never used your mentioned functions. Or be more elaborative so I can implement this Please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an idea of how one could asynchronously download a large number of images while simultaneously showing them in a ListBox, take a look at the following simplified view model, which declares a collection property for all downloaded images and an `async` method that performs the download.

The download is asynchronous because the method calls (and awaits) the async `HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync()` method.

For demonstration, it downloads 256 (map tile) images from `openstreetmap.org`.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; private set; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

    public async Task DownloadImages()
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        for (int y = 0; y < 16; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 16; x++)
            {
                var url = string.Format(
                    "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/4/{0}/{1}.png", x, y);

                // the await here makes the download asynchronous
                var buffer = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(url);

                using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                {
                    Images.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(
                        stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may set up your MainWindow's `DataContext` and start the download in a `Loaded` event handler like this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    DataContext = viewModel;

    Loaded += async (s, e) => await viewModel.DownloadImages();
}
```

Finally, the ListBox's XAML might look like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```