# WPF: Display images during execution

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a grid with a column to display images(success/failure ones, two separate images), am executing an api in for loop and based on the status I have to display images(success/failure, two separate images). I see images getting displayed all at a time after execution but not during execution one after another.

I referred - [How to load image to WPF in runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880946/how-to-load-image-to-wpf-in-runtime), but still not working.

```
public class DisplayImage
{ 

public static void DisplayImages(Image imgDisplay, HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            image.UriSource = new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, @"Image\Green_1.png"));
        }
        else
        {
            image.UriSource = new Uri(System.IO.Path.Combine(path, @"Image\Red.png"));
        }
        image.EndInit();
        imgDisplay.Source = image;
        imgDisplay.Refresh()
    }
}

    public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate () { };
    public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
    {
        uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
    }
}
```

I want the images to be displayed during run time itself and not after execution.

Comment: If this is supposed to run in a loop in the UI thread, there is a very simple solution. Make async web requests, e.g. [`HttpClient.GetAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetAsync_System_Uri_)

Comment: Besides that, if you have a variable number of images, you should consider using an ItemsControl with an Image element in its ItemTemplate, See e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37878325/1136211) for how to load images asynchronously in an ItemsControl.

Comment: @Clemens: This isn`t duplicate, it`s the same as the other thread which I already put in the post, it`s just that it isnt working. Also am using doing 'client.PostAsync'. I have added images in the grid without source and I`ll be setting source during runtime. I just want them to display while execution.

Comment: This is now fixed. I have updated my answer.

Comment: You probably missed an important detail in your question. It seems that you run the loop in a thread other than the UI thread. Note that this isn't necessary with async calls.

Comment: @Clemens - How can I correct this? Function 'DisplayImages' will be called in a for loop. I`ll be glad to learn and improve performances. Kindly edit my code.

Comment: It's all in the answer to the original question. There is a loop that runs in the UI thread, where async HTTP requests are made to download data.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused due to the work is blocking the UI thread from updating...

Top o mind I think you could do the work in a BackgroundWorker and use Dispatcher.Invoke calls to update the UI thread.

Comment: Yes! It worked when I did invoke dispatcher. Updated my code.